# Place for setting environment variables for WebSphere JVM process

Tags: linux, rhel6, websphere, oracle

I have a websphere application which runs under the user `wsadmin`.

The application invokes the SQL bulk loader client `./sqlldr`

The sqlldr needs some environment variables predefined in order to work such as

`ORACLE_BASE=/usr/app/oracle`
`ORACLE_HOME=/usr/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.1/client_64`
`ORACLE_SID=VDO1018`

Can you tell me what is the best place to put these variables. I have few options:

1) /etc/profile or /etc/environment

2) .bash_profile of wsadmin user

The reason I am asking this question is sqlldr is failing randomly for us and currently the variables are placed in .bash_profile. since .bash_profile is used for login shells, I am not sure if it would apply for JVM process.

Comment: So you're running an application under WebSphere Application Server processes, correct? Not just running something from the shell as the same user that runs WebSphere Application Server?

Comment: yes, running an application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to try setting this in WebSphere Application Server:

Using the administrative console, navigate to **Servers > Server types > WebSphere application servers > *server_name* > Server Infrastructure > Java and Process Management > Process Definition > Environment Entries**

There you can add your environment variable. Please note that if you are running the application clustered on multiple servers, you would need to set this for all of them.

*Add:* I just also found a technote explaining this: http://ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21254153